# Download only the selenium (Python 2.7) I need

Tags: python, selenium, python-2.7

How to download only the selenium (Python 2.7) I need pictures and scripts? And how do I get the data from the image of the loaded page?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html.

What platform are you running on?